# Why is Nietzsche considered a philosopher - but not Whitman?

Tags: ethics, nietzsche

Reading Whitmans epic - *The Leaves of Grass* recently; I was so struck by his language and it's similarity to Nietzsches that I suspected that he had been influenced or read him.

For example:

> I celebrate myself, and sing myself
>
> And what I assume you shall assume

Which sounds like a possible conception of the *Uberman*; and

> Do I contradict myself
>
> Very well then, I contradict myself
>
> I am large, I contain multitudes

Which as an idea appears in Nietzsche.

Further, consider that both positioned themselves as bards and prophets.

But this appears to be not the case; but it does appears that both were influenced by the Transcendentalism of Emerson: the *over-soul* and his 'foolish consistency'.

But why is one taken to be a philosopher and the other a poet; when it appears that both were philosopher-poets?

Comment: Focus. Poetry, like music, is a drug (insofar as drug means mind altering in terms of emotion). What are the authors/producers focused on - truth or evoking emotion?

Comment: I think it's more to do with the fact that Nietzsche was involved in the academic humanities (he had a PhD in philology). Nietzsche's non-poetic works are read just as much as Zarathustra, whereas Whitman's non-poetic works are rarely studied.

Comment: @RonRoyston but can Nietzsche be said to be focused on truth?  The writings of his that I read weren't logical arguments, but bombastic, emotional assertions.  Maybe the argument is there and I missed it, or maybe I just read bad Nietzsche.  Whatever the case, I don't see how he's any more philosophical than Emerson.

Comment: @royston: to compare poetry to a drug is already a kind of metaphor; and aren't you presenting an argument?

Comment: @MoziburUllah True.  I am thinking that poetry (and music)  evokes emotion whereas philosophy is sobering.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree both are philosopher-poets, though I would add many other qualities.  However, I am inclined to point out from a purely academic perspective,if a case had to be made as to why they're dropped into either a "philosopher" group or a "poet" group, the focus of each sets them up to be lumped into those groups.